# WYSIWYG data driven graph generator

Tags: .net, charts, components

I'm creating quite a few SSIS packages to drive document composition (e.g. utility bills, statements, etc). These require complex graphs in some cases, mostly bar or line graphs (some with bars and lines)

Is there any charting program or library you can build a graph in a WYSIWYG environment (preferably selecting sample data to work off), then point it to the live data and click "generate"? Think excel like charting, but being able to iterate through records and create graphs for each. The program will need to save images (any format is fine) of the graphs.

Ideally this would be able to be scripted either as a .Net component or via command line.

At the moment I'm using the MS charting library, but this is a bit tedious to use on a daily basis (as you need to set all the properties, no nice wizards). I've looked at RChart, which has a WYSIWYG designer, but it's java unfortunately.

Also looked at Zedgraph, which would be good if there's no other alternative, but it does take a while to set up the graph.

If there's no library or scripable component, do you know of any interactive programs that can do this (i.e. select data source, define graph, generate images)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the big one, [Dundas Chart](http://www.dundas.com/Products/Chart/index.aspx)? It has WYSIWYG and wizard features, and a metric butt-load of features.

I've used ZedGraph, and you're right, there's a lot of property fiddling to be done to get it to look and behave as you desire. Not to say that it isn't a great project, however!